# HTML5 Audio: Detecting when an actual click is required to play audio

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm using jQuery and I noticed that when I make it so that clicking on a link causes audio to play, it works fine on the iPad. As I understand it, the audio is only allowed to play because the user explicitly clicked on something. However, if I make it so that clicking on a link causes something to fade in and then the `fadeIn` callback plays the audio, it doesn't work on the iPad anymore unless you tap the link a second time (after the element has already been faded in). Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3sg2v/

Notice that in desktop browsers, you only need to click the link once for the audio to play.

I have found that the iPad is not the only device that behaves this way. I tried out the above example on a Motorola Xoom running Android 4.1.2 and got the same behavior in both the stock browser and Chrome 18.0.1025469. However, it works on my Motorola Droid 2 running Android 2.3.4 in both the stock browser and Firefox 20.0.1 (only one tap on the link is required for the audio to play).

My question is **what is the most elegant way to detect this behavior?**

Comment: Why not simply call `$('#audio_test')[0].play();` outside the `fadeIn` callback?

Comment: @idbehold This was just a simple example, but if I wanted to do several different things before playing the audio and I didn't know exactly how long those things would take, what would I do then?

Comment: hm, tablets that dont support jq callbacks...have you tried using pure javascript?

Comment: @MikeHometchko The tablets do support jQuery callbacks. The issue is that certain devices like the iPad are set up so that audio can only be played if it appears that the user initiated it. The Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide has a section called "iOS-Specific Considerations". Within that is a subsection called [User Control of Downloads Over Cellular Networks](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4) that explains it more.

Comment: probably a constraint due to outrageous provider data restrictions.  I'd say you probably cant get around it without coding a NaCl app rather than relying on http protocols.  However, I believe the audio file would cache on page load wouldn't it?  If so you aren't downloading anything when clicking on it.  Hrmmm

Comment: Most mobile devices refuse to cache audio at all. The reason he's having issues is that (on iOS anyways) the audio can only be played if the user  physically initiated the action **on the same callstack**. Hence, you cannot do any asynchronous operations in between the click event and playing the audio. jQuery's `fadeIn()` is an example of an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Wow that sort of ruins callback functionality altogether doesn't it?  Sounds aggravating to say the least, I survive off of callbacks at times.

Comment: You can still use callbacks, they just have to be synchronous. You just can't use things like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` (like [jQuery Animations](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js) do) or any other native APIs that aren't synchronous (i.e. FileSystem API, IndexedDB API, etc.). You *can*, however, perform **synchronous XMLHttpRequests** (this is the only use-case I've actually seen for using synchronous XHRs) in between the click event and initializing audio playback and it will work just fine on iOS.

Comment: @idbehold What do you think about using something like this to detect this behavior? I haven't tested this on the Motorola Xoom, but it seems to work on the iPad (it alerts "false"). `test_audio_played = false; $('<audio>').on('play', function() {test_audio_played = true;})[0].play(); setTimeout(function() {alert(test_audio_played);}, 1);`

Comment: @idbehold I tested that code on some more devices and it seems to work. By the way, it seems like you *can* use `setTimeout` on iOS as long as the delay you pass it is <= 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQxG5/)):

```
test_audio_played = false;

$('<audio>').on('play', function() {
    test_audio_played = true;
})[0].play();

setTimeout(function() {
    alert(test_audio_played);
}, 1);
```

Desktop browsers and my Motorola Droid 2 running Android 2.3.4 all alert "true", as expected and the iPad and that Motorola Xoom running Android 4.1.2 alert "false", as expected.